# resource request: variational bicomplex

Tags: differential-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation, online-resources, variational-analysis

I have recently come across the variational bi-complex and understand it to be an extension of Lagrangians and am interested in learning more about it, in particular regarding its relationship with Lagrangians and the Eurler-Lagrange equation. So far I've come across Ian Anderson's book on the subject but am wondering if there are any more condensed resources (which might not be as complete) or set of video lectures that might give a bit more intuition before digging through that book (or if there is a better book to initially learn from).

For trying to judge relevant resources would estimate my mathematical skill level to be somewhere between a Masters student/early PhD level (though since I'm from physics I also suspect my breadth and depth of knowledge is a little unusual).

Comment: You've probably seen this already, but nlab has lots of pointers: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/variational+bicomplex#references

Comment: Yeah, I think that was where I found Ian's book